# What I need to develop applications for windows phone 8.1?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I would like learn a bit how to develop applications for windows phone 8.1, so I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Community.

But in the requierements I can see this:

For Windows Phone development:

```
Windows Phone 8.0 development requires Windows 8.1 (x64) or higher
Windows Phone 8.1 development requires Windows 8.1 (x86) or higher
For the Windows Phone emulators, Windows 8.1 (x64) Professional
edition or higher, and a processor that supports Client Hyper-V and
Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
```

So for windows phone 8 I need windows x64 and for windows 8.1 I need x86? I can develop applications for windows phone 8.1 with the community version of visual studio?

Thank so much.

Comment: If you meet the configuration requirements... then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Windows 8, you can develop apps for Windows Phone 8.1.
Architecture doesn't matter, I run a x64 W8.1 using the Express edition of VS2013, and can develop apps for ARM, x86, and x64 all the same.

I think the only reason to use Windows 8.1 is to use Universal App templates.

Comment: Then, if I understand, you can develop applications for windows phone 8.1 with windows 8.1 x64 and VS2013 Express? And you can select windows Phone 8 or windows phoe 8.1 target? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, that is my setup. I'm not at my home computer right now, but I'm **fairly sure** you can set your target to either WP8 or WP8.1.